# Is there a better way to display each element of a content wrapper after a certain time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to display each div inside the `content-wrapper` after a certain time.
I currently use the `el1, el2, el3, ...` classes to achieve this goal. But some of my `content-wrappers` have multiple elements, which makes it less elegant as each class has to be unique. Is there a better way to achieve this, for example by using the `el` class common to each sub-element of the content-wrapper div.

I currently have this html and js.

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
   <div class="el el1">1</div>
   <div class="el el2">2</div>
   <div class="el el3">3</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function display_elt(elt_class, time){
   setTimeout(function(){
       document.querySelector(elt_class);
   }, time)
}

var time_int = 0; 
divs = ['elt1', 'elt2', 'elt3'];
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  time_int  += 0.5;
  function display_elt(divs[i], time_int);
}
```

A solution with CSS, Javascript or JQuery will be welcome.

Comment: Do you want *div1* will display first, then *div2*, then *div3* with a pause of *0.5s*? I can do it with CSS only (if yes, I will answer)

Comment: Yes, CSS is also fine. I want each element to come 0.5s after the previous one.

Comment: ok, pls wait @kyv 5 minutes or also less :) i will answer (I have a mini-idea of this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just using *pure plain CSS*

all the code is commented.

---

useful documentations:

- [CSS variables MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)
- [CSS `calc()` MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc())
- [CSS `forwards` animation fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

```css
* {
  /* this is a css variable */
  --delay: 0.5s;
}

.el {
  /* hidden by default */
  opacity: 0;
  /* shorthand -> name duration timing-function fill-mode */
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s linear forwards;
  /* the real trick is here */
  animation-delay: calc(var(--delay) * var(--i));
  /*el1 -> 0.5s * 0 = 0 */
  /*el2 -> 0.5s * 1 = 0.5s */
  /*el3 -> 0.5s * 2 = 1s */
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    /* is not visible*/
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    /* is visible */
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <!-- 0 -->
  <div style="--i: 0;" class="el el1">1</div>
  <!-- 1 -->
  <div style="--i: 1;" class="el el2">2</div>
  <!-- 2 -->
  <div style="--i: 2;" class="el el3">3</div>
  <!-- if more elements, increase the --i css variable for next elements -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Laaouatni, this is exactly what I want. But, is it possible to use either pure CSS, JavaScript or JQuery ? I am not using Vanilla in this project.

Comment: @Kyv vanilla means plain

Comment: @Kyv this is pure CSS :) but advanced... still normal CSS, I added some documentation for the thing I think you don't know

Comment: added more comments in the code, so you can understand well

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong with your code.
First, you seem to be selecting the element but you aren't doing anything with it.

Second, you have several syntax errors in your code:
incorrect use of `function` keyword, reference to wrong variable, etc.

Here are the corrections you need to make:

```js
function display_elt(elt_class, time){
   setTimeout(function(){
       document.querySelector('.'+elt_class).hidden = false; // make the element NOT hidden
   }, time)
}

var time_int = 0; 
var divs = ['el1', 'el2', 'el3'];
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) { // use 'divs.length' (which is 3 not 4)
  time_int  += 0.5;
  display_elt(divs[i], time_int); // call the function with 'divs[i]'
}
```

and in your html, just set each element to be initially hidden

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
   <div class="el el1" hidden>1</div>
   <div class="el el2" hidden>2</div>
   <div class="el el3" hidden>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @skara9. I didn't test that example, because I think there is a better solution using the `el` class.